# ajax - undefined index of input file from server

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload

I'm trying to upload file using ajax and php, but the console output is something like this `Message:  Undefined index: photo`

Here is the html code:

```
<input id="photo" name="photo" type="file" onchange="$('#preview')[0].src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])" required/>

<input type="button" value="Upload" id="btn_photo" />
```

Ajax code:

```
var form_data = new FormData();                  

form_data.append('file', 'photo'); # html input name     

$.ajax({
url         : "<?php echo base_url('upload') ?>",
type        : "POST",
data        : form_data,
contentType : false,       
cache       : false,             
processData : false,
enctype     : 'multipart/form-data',        
dataType    : 'JSON',
success: function(data) {               
       var obj = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));

       if(obj['status']) {
             alert('success');
       }
},
error: function (data) {
       console.log("AJAX error in request: " + JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
}
});
```

and this is the php code to handle upload process,

```
$image_name = $_FILES[$fieldname]['name'];
```

since the `$fieldname` is a variable to store html input file name, then it will replaced with value `photo`

I'm not using form tag to upload the file in my html code, did i miss something?
Can someone please help me with the error?

**EDIT**

According to this ref [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) 
I should append file data like this

```
formData.append('userpic[]', myFileInput1.files[0], 'chris1.jpg');
```

So, i updated these line

```
var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append('file', 'photo'); # html input name
```

into this

```
var form_data = new FormData();                  
var file = document.getElementById("photo").files[0];
form_data.append('file', file, $("#photo").val());
```

Then i got this error `undefined offset 0`
Can someone please help?

Comment: Do you actually use `form_data.append('file', 'photo')` in your real code? Because that would only add a **string** "photo" to parameter "file".

Comment: yes sir :( so, what should i do? @Passerby

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append#Example

Comment: please take a look on my updated question sir @Passerby

Comment: in controller try `print_r($_FILES);` and see what you are getting.

Comment: it is resulted `Array( [file] => Array ([name] => IMG (3rd copy).JPG [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => /tmp/php0tHxgm [error] => 0 [size] => 37325))` @NiranjanNRaju when i test with image

Comment: @lloistborn Please point out which PHP line produced the error? From your `print_r($_FILES)` the file has been successfully uploaded.

Comment: Yes it is uploaded. The error is in `$_FILES['htmlInputName']['name']`, i'm using the `htmlInputName` from the body tag instead the form element in ajax. Since the Array contains value `file` in output above, i just changed `$_FILES['htmlInputName']['name']` into `$_FILES['file']['name']`. That was close :) thank you for all the response @Passerby
Also i will edit my question shortly